# Is there a way to stop an update while keeping updated rows in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

So I have 2 huge tables, one is updating from another one and the query has been running for over 1 day. Now there's a bunch of more important work that I need to do so I'll need to bring the laptop home which means that I'll have to stop the query

Is there a way to keep the changes of already changed rows instead of everything going back pre update?

Comment: No, not possible. A single update statement is always atomic.

Comment: You need to divide the table onto groups and run 1 UPDATE query for 1 group. But remember that functions in PostgreSQL are wrapped into transactions automatically - it means that if you write multiple such UPDATEs in 1 function and than stop it, changes from ALL UPDATEs will rollback.